# MongoDB Realm: Create User is Slow

Tags: mongodb, realm

We have MongoDB Atlas with App Services & Data Services and are using this method to create a user but it consistently takes 1200ms to 1800ms

Is there any way to speed this up?

```
https://realm.mongodb.com/api/admin/v3.0/groups/groupID/apps/appID/users
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application.json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer &Token&`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"email": "test@test.com", "password": "12345678!", "status": "Pending"})
```

I have tried increasing the size of the Database but this made no difference.

To test this without my on environment as a factor I used the 'Add New User' button in the UI and timed the response to this request:

```
https://realm.mongodb.com/api/admin/v3.0/groups/xxx/apps/yyy/users
```

As you can see here it took 610ms to add the user:

[image]

Here are the timings I got for different regions and dedicated/serverless:

[image]

As you can see the speed varies wildly in different locations, and all of them are at least 400ms

Do you know if there's any way to speed this up?

Comment: Creating a user in Realm Authentication happens almost instantly so it's not clear why it's slow for you. Also, there's not enough code in the question to understand the use case as that code doesn't create or register a new user. Can you clarify? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The most minimal example I could make is by clicking 'Add New User' in the Atlas GUI and timing the request it makes. I've updated the question with more info.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading the code but I am not seeing any Realm code that actually creates a user. I would expect to see `.createUser` or some such function.